# Subclass of QGraphicsItem only receives hover event on the border from bounding rectangle

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm developing with Qt-5.15.1. I want to customize `QGraphicsItem`, and in this customized item one rectangle and some surrounding circles added. The little circles will show when the mouse is hovering on that rectangle. So I reimplement the `hoverEnterEvent` and `hoverLeaveEvent` function to receive mouse hover event, please refer to `minimal example`.

Then, in `paint` event I can determine whether draw circles or not based on `_mouseEnter`.

Here comes the problem, I found the `hoverEnterEvent` will triggered as soon as mouse enter the border of that rectangle, however quickly `hoverLeaveEvent` is also triggered as mouse go through the border, being near the center of rectangle. Seems the border is the entity of mouse hover event, not the filled rectangle. So I can only show circles on when mouse is hovering on the border of that rectangle.

I don't know if I miss something? In my opinion, `shape()` and `boundingRect()` will affect these mouse events on **when event happens**? I want to make `shape()` to return a filled rectangle of `QPainterPath`, but don't know how to.

Update: **minimal example**

**customizeitem.cpp**

```cpp
#include "customizeitem.h"
#include <QDebug>

CustomizeItem::CustomizeItem(QGraphicsItem *parent):
  QGraphicsItem(parent),
  _bbox(0,0,120, 120),_radius(7),
  _mouseEnter(false)
{
  setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
  setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

  _rectRect = QRect(QPoint(_radius*4, _radius*4), QPoint(_bbox.width() - _radius*4, _bbox.height() - _radius*4));

  QPointF upCenter(_bbox.width()/2, _radius);
  QPointF rCenter(_bbox.width() - _radius, _bbox.height() / 2);
  QPointF downCenter(_bbox.width()/2, _bbox.height() - _radius);
  QPoint lCenter(_radius, _bbox.height() / 2);
  _anchorRects.push_back(QRectF(upCenter, QSizeF(_radius, _radius)));
  _anchorRects.push_back(QRectF(rCenter, QSizeF(_radius, _radius)));
  _anchorRects.push_back(QRectF(downCenter, QSizeF(_radius, _radius)));
  _anchorRects.push_back(QRectF(lCenter, QSizeF(_radius, _radius)));
}

void CustomizeItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
  qInfo() << "mouse enter";
  _mouseEnter = true;

  update();
  QGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(event);
}

void CustomizeItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
  qInfo() << "mouse leave";
  _mouseEnter = false;

  update();
  QGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(event);
}

QRectF CustomizeItem::boundingRect() const
{
  return shape().boundingRect();
}

void CustomizeItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *)
{
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  drawAnchors(painter);
  painter->fillRect(_rectRect, QColor(255, 0, 0));
}

QPainterPath CustomizeItem::shape() const
{
  QPainterPath path;
  path.moveTo(_bbox.topLeft());
  path.addRect(_bbox);
  QPainterPathStroker stroker;
  stroker.setWidth(10);
  return stroker.createStroke(path);
}

void CustomizeItem::drawAnchors(QPainter *painter)
{
  if(_mouseEnter)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < _anchorRects.size(); i++)
    {
      QPainterPath path;
      path.moveTo(_anchorRects[0].center());
      path.addEllipse(_anchorRects[i].center(), _radius, _radius);

      painter->drawPath(path);
    }
  }
}
```

**customizeitem.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CUSTOMIZEITEM_H
#define CUSTOMIZEITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPainter>

class CustomizeItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  enum { Type = UserType + 1 };

  explicit CustomizeItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);
  ~CustomizeItem() = default;

protected:
  void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
  void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
  QRectF boundingRect() const;
  void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *);
  QPainterPath shape() const;
private:
  void drawAnchors(QPainter *painter);

  QRect _bbox;

  float _radius; // radius for circle anchor
  QVector<QRectF> _anchorRects;

  QRect _rectRect;
  bool _mouseEnter;
};

#endif // CUSTOMIZEITEM_H
```

**maiwindow.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "customizeitem.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget());
  layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

  QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
  view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

  CustomizeItem *item = new CustomizeItem;
  scene->addItem(item);

  view->setScene(scene);
  layout->addWidget(view);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi~, where and how should I attach my minimal example?  For now, I just copy them here, and I'll remove them if this is not suitable.

Comment: read the link, also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: thanks, I have add a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPainterPathStroker generates a hollow region around the rectangle so as soon as that border passes it is already out of the shape. The solution is to join that edge with the inner region:

```cpp
QPainterPath CustomizeItem::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.moveTo(_bbox.topLeft());
    path.addRect(_bbox);
    QPainterPathStroker stroker;
    stroker.setWidth(10);
    QPainterPath strokerPath = stroker.createStroke(path);
    strokerPath.addPath(path); // join
    return strokerPath;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for cannot vote due to lack of reputation.

Comment: @taptiptop please review the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Or just adjust the bounding box rectangle to accommodate the extra size.

```cpp
QPainterPath CustomizeItem::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(_bbox.adjusted(-5, -5, 5, 5));
    return path;
}
```

Since your "hit" shape is rectangular, you can probably just re-implement `boundingRect()`, since the default `QGraphicsItem::shape()` actually uses `boundingRect()` result (according to [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape)).

```cpp
QRectF CustomizeItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(_bbox.adjusted(-5, -5, 5, 5));
}
```

Comment: Have tried, but not work. Do I miss something?